# Are there open-source alternatives to ArcGIS online that can be hosted on my own server?

Tags: qgis, web-mapping, software-recommendations, qgis-server

I know this might be too broad topic. But I am looking for web-GIS portal similar to ArcGIS online that is self-installable (configurable) to be hosted in my private server. The main features should include:

- Users can upload and interact with spatial data (shp, CSV, KML, JSON etc)
- Users can rate, comment and download layers submitted by others

In my opinion, QGIS-server, QGIS-web-client and/or QGIS cloud could develop to be a full featured cloud service that can be deployed on any server.

Answer (score 12):

The closest thing to what you want that I could think of is [GeoNode](http://opengeo.org/technology/geonode/).

> GeoNode is an open source platform that facilitates the creation,
>   sharing, and collaborative use of geospatial data.

[image]

It allows you to upload files, create and edit maps and metadata, and also to rate the data. You can also embed the maps you create in GeoNode on your own web pages. The data is downloadable as well. The following are the supported export formats:

- ESRI Shapefile
- Google Earth KML
- Adobe PDF
- Microsoft Excel
- CSV (comma delimited text)
- GML (geographic markup language)
- PNG (image)
- JPEG (image)
- View in Google Earth

The latest release has support for comments and ratings on map and layers. It also has social features( e.g. you can ‘like’ a layer on Facebook and ‘+1′ it on Google Plus ).

Comment: Geonode is an excellent project with good support. The only challenge with it is that it will rewrite your apache setup. So beware of installing it on a server currently hosting other projects.

Comment: Great! Geonode seems an excellent package which needs to have more community support. I am testing it on Ubuntu and it have some dependency issues with gdal and django. Also it would have been great to be able to add WMS from rest end points of ArcGIS server.

Answer (score 5):

Also see [OpenGeo Suite](http://opengeo.org/products/suite/). It ships with geoserver, PostGIS(DB), OpenLayers(viewer), GeoExt (UI). They have a [cloud Edition](http://opengeo.org/products/suite/cloud/) as well

Answer (score 2):

[Esri Geoportal Server](https://github.com/Esri/geoportal-server) is an

> open source product that enables discovery and use of geospatial resources including data and services

Might be an interesting alternatives (albeit far fetched in terms of features) to Geonode.

Answer (score 1):

Give also a look to MyGeoCloud. It's still in beta but seems promising
http://beta.mygeocloud.com/

Answer (score -2):

I have been trying giscloud.com, works fine so far. You could set up a trial account and test it for 30 days. Is really intuitive and easy to use. Supports both vector and raster data.